# JSON file becomes corrupted when writing to file in .Net Framewrork

Tags: json, .net, vb.net

Several times a year I come upon a JSON (or XML) file that gets corrupted. It seems to happen in the memory buffer when writing the data. I have a program that writes several GeoJsons. Typically these files are written all at once and are not changed. Here is an example of a corrupt JSON file.

```json
{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[-95.90581755,45.967351695,1256.967414294819,1252.1346109527701,1252.1328967485022],[-95.905830492,45.967353399,1256.9684269038298,1252.1379330548141,1252.1157774438909],[-95.905844003,45.967353326,1256.9694722523925,1252.14139496894,1252.1355866406259],[-95.90585747,45.967352804,1256.9705113860718,1252.156630739054,1252.156839439876],[-95.905870938,45.967352335,1256.971550894079,1252.2023749010923,1252.1694715015867],[-95.905884265,45.967351807,1256.972579195887,1252.3009469431331,1252.1864718098063],[-95.905897884,45.967351861,1256.973633900318,1252.4045763771298,1252.2368533307044],[-95.905911361,45.96735116,1256.9746727613751,1252.5298519357223,1252.3372136630414],[-95.905924704,45.967350669,1256.975702617317,1252.6982161008198,1252.4547550268003],[-95.905938801,45.967350621,1256.976793672234,1252.8504839238003,1252.6017786828522],[-95.905951797,45.967350342,1256.9777980419794,1252.9927667794984,1252.7554007646411],[-95.905965508,45.967350066,1256.978857676354,1253.1567175890125,1252.9238213750255],[-95.90597957,45.967349736,1256.9799442174819,1253.3362635711042,1253.0612344374574],[-95.905992871,45.967349595,1256.9809731327109,1253.4672224264957,1253.2181970618028],[-95.906006268,45.967349382,1256.9820090061869,1253.5859300150728,1253.3894003962905],[-95.906019607,45.967348904,1256.9999900261566,1253.6919587896866,1253.5562614189612],[-95.906033926,45.967348459,1257.1164422784798,1253.7877390331387,1253.7151092125837],[-95.906047291,45.967348656,1257.2180310678075,1253.833155834478,1253.8071532335719],[-95.906060598,45.967348359,1257.3438238396961,1253.8861465831858,1253.8643185981718],[-95.906074163,45.967348583,1257.4602665887394,1254.0062837223811,1253.897701794062],[-95.906087818,45.967348726,1257.5731551811475,1254.1221563711949,1253.9430771350605],[-95.906101728,45.967348837,1257.7165278075013,1254.2420745052332,1254.0158617355899],[-95.906115578,45.967348805,1257.8094270913707,1254.3501376798324,1254.1432822021138],[-95.906129816,45.967349506,1257.9265423050551,1254.4588951772287,1254.3007451009646],[-95.906143107,45.967349814,1258.02852270017,1254.5647212076444,1254.4328772990671],[-95.906156918,45.967350219,1258.1298117616657,1254.6881687740815,1254.5394332355215],[-95.906170962,45.967350437,1258.2774959773083,1254.8166181815709,1254.6471893541757],[-95.906184148,45.967350561,1258.3900800436877,1254.9260708069344,1254.7576638463879],[-95.906197455,45.967350622,1258.4889387089354,1255.0311843098114,1254.8798021407026],[-95.906211276,45.967351042,1258.6081189357324,1255.1539942972961,1255.0049332957499],[-95.9062254,45.967351036,1258.73211315691,1255.2788640115527,1255.1176093954186],[-95.906239355,45.967351339,1258.8661701249903,1255.4018013361929,1255.227130482333],[-95.906252825,45.96735102,1258.969955531803,1255.5086701710122,1255.3368612308338],[-95.906266099,45.967351731,1259.0882537822101,1255.6152653294728,1255.462828317975],[-95.906279841,45.967351697,1259.1803402435246,1255.7128651303287,1255.588093216485],[-95.906293469,45.967351742,1259.2857259798691,1255.8120620621435,1255.6838744368488],[-95.906306413,45.96735205,1259.3752963237575,1255.8986358691293,1255.7698586211166],[-95.906320118,45.967352106,1259.4645297326667,1255.9857433302384,1255.859610517655],[-95.906334193,45.967351502,1259.5498315673583,1256.07104516493,1255.9557791141692],[-95.906347921,45.96735191,1259.6271615385006,1256.1438362855231,1256.0619419194354],[-95.90636176,45.967351872,1259.6982221618057,1256.2156306049717,1256.13034454484],[-95.906375035,45.967351553,1259.7729658930182,1256.2869696642356,1256.1820442157014],[-95.90638822,45.967351749,1259.8377105681727,1256.3517143393904,1256.2464499029627],[-95.906402307,45.967351934,1259.901324932333,1256.4113558143943,1256.320607256039],[-95.906415909,45.967351762,1259.9509343268257,1256.4575692910553,1256.3886543326682],[-95.906430117,45.967351757,1259.9977830869959,1256.5039141562825,1256.4510809110773],[-95.906443844,45.967351364,1260.0408120570714,1256.5465653182903,1256.4948734125496],[-95.906457096,45.967351315,1260.0857675089487,1256.5922976900736eDismImage
2023-11-17 14:01:42, Info                  DISM   API: PID=5000 TID=11804 Target image information: OS Version=10.0.17763.4377, Image architecture=amd64 - CDismCore::LogImageSessionDetails
2023-11-17 14:01:42, Info                  DISM   API: PID=5000 TID=8924 Leave DismOpenSessionInternal - DismOpenSessionInternal
2023-11-17 14:01:42, Info                  DISM   API: PID=5000 TID=8924 Session id is: 2 - DismOpenSessionInternal
2023-11-17 14:01:42, Info                         SetupClnLogInitializationInfo - Getting plugin name
2023-11-17 14:01:42, Info                         SetupClnLogInitializationInfo - session being initialized for Plugin: Upgrade Discarded Files
2023-11-17 14:01:42, Info                         Client Process:C:\Windows\system32\cleanmgr.exe
2023-11-17 14:01:42, Info                         pszWellKnownDirs:$WINDOWS.~Q;$INPLACE.~TR;$Windows.~LS
2023-11-17 14:01:42, Info                         bCleanWindowsOld:0
2023-11-17 14:01:42, Info                         bRemoveUninstall:0
2023-11-17 14:01:42, Info                         bShowOnlyInUpgrade:0
2023-11-17 14:01:42, Info                         bShowOnlyInESDInstall:0
2023-11-17 14:01:42, Info                         bSilentCleanup:1
2023-11-17 14:01:42, Info                         bCleanupTemporaryInstallationFiles:0
2023-11-17 14:01:42, Info                         CSetupFilesCleanup::GetSpaceUsed - Calculating the space for session: Upgrade Discarded Files
2023-11-17 14:01:42, Info                         IsProcessElevated - bResult: 1
2023-11-17 14:01:42, Info                         CSetupFilesCleanup::CleanVolume - Iterating on: C:\$WINDOWS.~Q
... 30 more lines of log data...
2023-11-17 14:02:53, Info                  263.3575406595323,1263.2327073543559],[-95.908423049,45.967351801,1266.9262305158618,1263.4595763381419,1263.3239264803869],[-95.908436069,45.967351983,1267.0232654504921,1263.5477074873011,1263.4261432556516],[-95.908449451,45.967351683,1267.1103122147076,1263.6334523258784,1263.5179380931797],[-95.908463283,45.967351447,1267.1987960808294,1263.7290390266512,1263.6148411657427],[-95.908476225,45.967351393,1267.2919360968242,1263.83829966889,1263.7002956142549],[-95.908489884,45.967351043,1267.4146418833502,1263.9496638771664,1263.7956952370059],[-95.908504475,45.967351238,1267.5292628978648,1264.0637861038749,1263.8965604608616],[-95.908517828,45.967351639,1267.6343921162177,1264.1769047641976,1264.0221545886561],[-95.908531779,45.967351303,1267.7543924463619,1264.3111516920324,1264.1707305277462],[-95.908545735,45.967351159,1267.89233687276,1264.4393578679469,1264.2954745557593],[-95.908559527,45.967350573,1268.0188074229361,1264.5710114272456,1264.3999493275287],[-95.908572621,45.967351131,1268.14186472212,1264.683178678868,1264.5154466082968],[-95.908587128,45.967350672,1268.2984352956671,1264.7984352956671,1264.6345014976584],[-95.908600716,45.967350878,1268.3699828995132,1264.907385060623,1264.7616042123743],[-95.908614454,45.967351042,1268.4833283786866,1265.0249273305149,1264.8785964428846],[-95.908628198,45.967351054,1268.6014716312552,1265.1431660775518,1264.9901139155609],[-95.908641558,45.967351426,1268.7139034176992,1265.2505965600258,1265.0975080104279],[-95.908655069,45.967351231,1268.8177374659956,1265.34239144282,1265.2001722635541],[-95.908668655,45.96735124,1268.9091366766336,1265.4438305719864,1265.3078348517995],[-95.908682512,45.967351515,1269.0177670075857,1265.5560211879911,1265.3994807849563],[-95.908696517,45.967351398,1269.1306722333197,1265.6603564565785,1265.5051259008876],[-95.908710531,45.96735195,1269.2273099247029,1265.7430263286194,1265.6039602099588],[-95.908723607,45.967351431,1269.2960485475596,1265.815105839853,1265.7028628499722],[-95.908736589,45.967351833,1269.3705252976481,1265.8897770994085,1265.7972145960416],[-95.908749489,45.967351746,1269.4445101050699,1265.9590688951359,1265.8848377973466],[-95.908763078,45.96735179,1269.5122471932521,1266.0292233406306,1265.9654544496161],[-95.908776619,45.967352143,1269.5844595702272,1266.0961792423063,1266.0217451035785],[-95.908789971,45.967352232,1269.6446292359428,1266.1600766509323,1266.0622971619634],[-95.908804502,45.967352097,1269.7193147092523,1266.2322473661989,1266.1161389525332],[-95.908817947,45.967352116,1269.7824805927251,1266.2923101482288,1266.1836240016435],[-95.908831412,45.967352294,1269.8385442800979,1266.35040998283,1266.2703710930332],[-95.908845704,45.967352072,1269.9025292333677,1266.4136363432003,1266.343714436535],[-95.908859177,45.967351923,1269.9605179900332,1266.4690767267193,1266.3874746014151],[-95.9088725,45.967351957,1270.0110196286846,1266.5177962044115,1266.4261235866359],[-95.908885538,45.967351971,1270.0526630352415,1266.555368936002,1266.4607153562977],[-95.908898463,45.967352351,1270.078948813238,1266.5797658653755,1266.5141965565379],[-95.908911522,45.96735197,1270.0941337454376,1266.5946535291646,1266.5691307469667],[-95.908924752,45.967352653,1270.1069044470851,1266.6083706871284,1266.611938183247],[-95.908938804,45.967352577,1270.1292977309649,1266.6309826048173,1266.6256607749056],[-95.908953041,45.967352375,1270.1534868441718,1266.6552507126542,1266.6196816611223],[-95.908966678,45.967353127,1270.1773123855746,1266.6777690246224,1266.6278647471975],[-95.90897968,45.967353161,1270.188791386322,1266.6891480528002,1266.6480296252626],[-95.908993263,45.967353234,1270.1991578225147,1266.7007433542299,1266.6767866882594],[-95.909006596,45.967353244,1270.21947273215,1266.7233056020598,1266.7087181862598],[-95.909020424,45.967353319,1270.2543537243814,1266.7592013487738,1266.734315239416],[-95.909033973,45.967354118,1270.2938919167882,1266.7982333945533,1266.7554226017503],[-95.909047208,45.967353822,1270.330039563858,1266.8343810416231,1266.77161905983],[-95.909060117,45.967353953,1270.3668513857319,1266.8717537391608,1266.7988425558835],[-95.909073947,45.967354117,1270.4084204294988,1266.9138489003356,1266.8419132187978],[-95.90908715,45.967354069,1270.4510570637547,1266.957574392083,1266.8877854320262],[-95.909100852,45.967354247,1270.4855599812081,1266.9875391111937,1266.9317222582749],[-95.909114214,45.967354664,1270.5050741559855,1267.0060215495523,1266.9706853445596],[-95.909127665,45.967353997,1270.5274356418824,1267.0296422612339,1267.0044153372116],[-95.909141104,45.967354286,1270.5579855885239,1267.0623160273008,1267.0387808169949],[-95.909155071,45.967354704,1270.5952565446912,1267.0990536214924,1267.0689645963271],[-95.909169211,45.967354471,1270.6325503851306,1267.1374755498459,1267.0830043950575],[-95.909182193,45.96735471,1270.6718995376775,1267.1787905686901,1267.1104047646922],[-95.909195153,45.967353928,1270.7145105698287,1267.2175826984108,1267.1541332834008],[-95.909208044,45.967354423,1270.7439932148523,1267.2466513567115,1267.2060902403643],[-95.909221787,45.967354205,1270.7740758622476,1267.2781520215685,1267.247733870777],[-95.909235876,45.967354363,1270.8114694209348,1267.31610066294,1267.2752043090873],[-95.909249333,45.967354232,1270.8494655951547,1267.3558473337962,1267.3047736598219],[-95.909262963,45.9673537,1270.8949105581046,1267.400142754776,1267.3380487451072],[-95.909276067,45.967353497,1270.9327450295261,1267.4400338219939,1267.3741387383807],[-95.909290508,45.967353693,1270.9799439205422,1267.4930080010904,1267.4322229442055],[-95.909303781,45.967353338,1271.045028036699,1267.5550364193193,1267.4886340779603],[-95.90931817,45.967353625,1271.102995876633,1267.6171517967603,1267.5500721410269],[-95.909331261,45.967353039,1271.1683377892487,1267.6814573937768,1267.6069493930174],[-95.909344211,45.967352691,1271.2343152959927,1267.743181988785,1267.657289950183],[-95.909357156,45.967352578,1271.2868881224249,1267.7941316330032,1267.7138904537705],[-95.909370632,45.967352021,1271.3259610319917,1267.8419559505642,1267.7798774035816],[-95.909383639,45.967351973,1271.3941022718775,1267.91009719045,1267.83847430692],[-95.909396885,45.967352131,1271.4652070443831,1267.9184927795382,1267.8975057744694],[-95.909411018,45.967352087,1271.542136499814,1267.9261863593235,1267.9274382407336],[-95.909425328,45.967352129,1271.6212881977681,1267.931016365241,1267.9477781608318],[-95.909439853,45.967351865,1271.685838378447,1267.9346647080542,1267.9562241752426],[-95.909453991,45.967351705,1271.7466555635,1267.9382553513196,1267.9583446278502],[-95.909468051,45.96735186,1271.8101365969562,1267.9418401871069,1267.9643204032236],[-95.909482321,45.967352448,1271.8638042265909,1267.94546849694,1267.9670087630902],[-95.909495294,45.967352462,1271.9115465040527,1267.9488020406584,1267.9657087213707],[-95.909509177,45.96735241,1271.9723853548412,1267.9523017456982,1267.9576653600329],[-95.909522558,45.967352635,1272.0307529438332,1267.9556894345612,1267.94586753382],[-95.909535784,45.967353168,1272.0770743644352,1267.9590539796411,1267.9440360800254],[-95.909549915,45.967353283,1272.1208239588805,1267.9627055102906,1267.9482923373253],[-95.909562879,45.967353428,1272.1596720065384,1267.9659788889974,1267.9678264932584],[-95.909575924,45.967353483,1272.1960535708263,1267.9693009569742,1267.9844465843391],[-95.909589483,45.967353592,1272.2335332524128,1267.9727386879308,1267.9812840109023],[-95.909602509,45.967354026,1272.2736686203832,1267.97605409635,1267.9738938634794],[-95.909615908,45.967354508,1272.3248101034153,1267.9794650530293,1267.9737257907716],[-95.909629376,45.967354885,1272.3621053967479,1267.9828914103839,1267.980986004851],[-95.90964258,45.967354713,1272.3762501765109,1267.9862502822268,1267.9872625314292],[-95.909655702,45.967355003,1272.3851592950809,1267.9895880455153,1267.9891594772332],[-95.909669055,45.96735519,1272.3948776764141,1267.9929803829618,1267.9934458306736],[-95.909681973,45.96735589,1272.4089329641454,1267.9962711369585,1267.9910905732906],[-95.909695545,45.967356032,1272.41722042065,1267.999746404085,1267.9867125513292],[-95.909709289,45.967355648,1272.4092233158324,1268.0032463591297,1267.9928326512475],[-95.909722817,45.967356357,1272.394033630794,1268.0066743054824,1268.0013847323685],[-95.909735778,45.967356001,1272.374413156421,1268.0099708510049,1268.0049377066866],[-95.909749709,45.96735637,1272.358466486528,1268.0135111422555,1268.0018232634784],[-95.909762692,45.967356218,1272.3333030401277,1268.0168219651146,1268.0125937705336],[-95.909776416,45.967356457,1272.3152685868072,1268.0203100504341,1268.0118588045348],[-95.90978961,45.967356226,1272.28887088863,1268.0236499418388,1268.0143375025232],[-95.909803668,45.967356202,1272.2736945769234,1268.027244043318,1268.0046553660186],[-95.909817149,45.967356865,1272.2598175905694,1268.0306723917374,1268.0180662812918],[-95.909830193,45.967356542,1272.238671387433,1268.034018349063,1268.0300434007663],[-95.909843232,45.967356303,1272.2211814383484,1268.0373016488406,1268.039472293138],[-95.909856978,45.967356645,1272.2015616374065,1268.0408089022778,1268.0334188486],[-95.909870315,45.967356418,1272.1866439583505,1268.0442022605002,1268.0255995174755],[-95.909884067,45.967356558,1272.1743611761349,1268.0476979543814,1268.0247086300606],[-95.909898837,45.967356548,1272.154859907009,1268.0514315951568,1268.0398808281627],[-95.909912796,45.967356548,1272.1204844309498,1268.0550764589436,1268.0554893525857],[-95.909926584,45.967356138,1272.0870932769283,1268.05853977297,1268.0567875967065],[-95.909939819,45.967356135,1272.0714633483933,1268.0619057621932,1268.0504409860221],[-95.909953119,45.967355856,1272.060240966277,1268.0652898973215,1268.0553720307798],[-95.90996756,45.967355882,1272.05665804588,1268.0689663385167,1268.0694530864778],[-95.909981419,45.967355632,1272.0479793338625,1268.0724928443453,1268.0720798667485],[-95.9099953,45.967355421,1272.03300220173,1268.0760213342314,1268.0667193696954],[-95.910008896,45.96735498,1272.0205089997464,1268.0794820749038,1268.0689586643198],[-95.910022674,45.967354975,1271.9963268079653,1268.0829846356596,1268.071335599541],[-95.910035576,45.967354439,1271.9876208705314,1268.0862598583499,1268.0739733363018],[-95.910048818,45.967354056,1271.9751342174247,1268.0896424369205,1268.0752599725881],[-95.910061904,45.96735438,1271.9760111571647,1268.092971407815,1268.0740608654112],[-95.910074817,45.967354385,1271.9775515996189,1268.0962524507279,1268.078721423647],[-95.910088064,45.967353783,1271.9725521959663,1268.0996466680178,1268.0885492996704],[-95.91010159,45.967353335,1271.9662633388916,1268.1030646552215,1268.0985144413169],[-95.910115919,45.967353429,1271.9704607078718,1268.1067191654759,1268.1038843729093],[-95.91012961,45.96735329,1271.9820203645686,1268.1101964725203,1268.1139667133866],[-95.910143635,45.967352877,1271.998755730951,1268.1137863691335,1268.1286067873673],[-95.910157144,45.967352632,1272.019476769158,1268.1172123072772,1268.1370296255739],[-95.910170749,45.967352771,1272.0504817347951,1268.1206525797736,1268.1421329907384],[-95.910183744,45.967352821,1272.077178634793,1268.1239744660397,1268.1285023613802],[-95.910197392,45.967352824,1272.0920844248878,1268.127433554311,1268.1252625090044],[-95.910210689,45.96735291,1272.1050722702096,1268.1307740645623,1268.1142906782941],[-95.910224716,45.967352758,1272.1175762500832,1268.1344167703387,1268.1106683814455],[-95.910238187,45.967353118,1272.1228595527054,1268.1378254642609,1268.1093125270033],[-95.91025141,45.967352999,1272.1163673757142,1268.1411695837874,1268.1255590352848],[-95.910264417,45.967353338,1272.1146119337786,1268.1445005981959,1268.1490270815279],[-95.910277905,45.96735265,1272.1183526423192,1268.1479538681924,1268.1550004843259],[-95.910291226,45.967353827,1272.1220374712186,1268.1513407131413,1268.1421015699379],[-95.910304155,45.967353973,1272.129655983206,1268.1546038629754,1268.1394483192471],[-95.910317363,45.967353826,1272.1330351533779,1268.15796880511,1268.1493495216666],[-95.910330624,45.967353445,1272.1392729557431,1268.1613429776548,1268.1632985618676],[-95.910343664,45.967354356,1272.1374958404615,1268.1646413228414,1268.174115189777],[-95.910356676,45.967354481,1272.1285185451393,1268.1679689614814,1268.171624762484],[-95.91036962,45.967355017,1272.1196728347736,1268.171240941726,1268.1703527458842],[-95.910382729,45.967355284,1272.1277454451547,1268.1746021016345,1268.1686243380855],[-95.910396101,45.967355384,1272.1369312602794,1268.1780029311212,1268.1758973504075],[-95.910409116,45.967355577,1272.1420494673525,1268.1813133283681,1268.1801298724688],[-95.910422729,45.967355392,1272.1283548707788,1268.1847558901302,1268.1889266270762],[-95.910436087,45.967355951,1272.1182597259592,1268.1881769953327,1268.193893043597],[-95.910449896,45.96735608,1272.1171837033642,1268.1917019516127,1268.1916154465748],[-95.910462942,45.967356019,1272.1254067831073,1268.1950032523132,1268.1812046526072],[-95.91047663,45.967356612,1272.1267772077474,1268.1985077833608,1268.1838047962112],[-95.910490497,45.967355945,1272.1157838424249,1268.2020432188774,1268.1881975584047],[-95.910504784,45.9673565,1272.09208836392,1268.2056607069339,1268.2015601513574],[-95.910518498,45.967356411,1272.0759642601756,1268.209195982932,1268.1990159426873],[-95.910531907,45.967356094,1272.0604817217022,1268.2126068378191,1268.2079472802513],[-95.910545118,45.967356868,1272.0459895480992,1268.2159747954627,1268.2009300700311],[-95.910558489,45.967356402,1272.0197342582499,1268.2193515310241,1268.2068899813692],[-95.910571758,45.967356146,1271.9888099986936,1268.2226247368947,1268.209965968387],[-95.910585084,45.967355815,1271.9590699935154,1268.2261396047306,1268.21412396416],[-95.910598296,45.967355832,1271.9341281521693,1268.2295130398202,1268.216978391983],[-95.910613626,45.967365839,1271.8996587737436,1268.2333953196214,1268.2264830736585]],"type":"LineString"},"id":"7","properties":{"ID":7,"Length":1222.29,"Vis":true,"Date":"5/12/2023","MinGrd":0.1,"MaxGrd":30.0,"MinDepth":2.5,"MaxDepth":6.0,"IdealDepth":3.5,"TileName":"4inch","TileType":"Sngl Corrugated","TileSize":4,"TileOD":4.6,"TilePerf":"Perf/Slotted","OvrcutWidth":10.0,"OvrcutDepth":0.0,"OvrcutVol":0.0,"OutletElev":1252.13,"OutletDepth":4.83,"Assoc":"Survey_7-30090.json","GKT_IDX":8},"type":"Feature"}
```

As you can see, the JSON string is being written, then part way through, a Windows log begins to write, then the GeoJson finishes. I have also seen instances where byte data is logged in the file and corrupts the GeoJson. This happens very rarely and is not consistent or easily reproducible.

Question: Why does this happen and is there a way in my code (.NET Framework: either VB.NET or C#) that I can prevent this from happening?

Below is my code (in VB.NET) for writing the GeoJson using GeoJson.net and Newtonsoft.Json

```
Dim line As New Feature.Feature(geometry, propDict, CStr(shape.Index))

Dim serializedData As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(line)

Using outputFile As New IO.StreamWriter(pathName, True)
    outputFile.WriteLine(serializedData)
End Using
```

Comment: Is it possible your logging code and JSON writing code are using the same temporary file?

Comment: It is not. The GeoJsons get saved to a separate project file. Also, this log data is not part of my log data. Reading the log data in the JSON, I am not using DISM anywhere in my code. So I can only assume that this is a windows log file.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the contents of `line` under the debugger to make sure that it contains what you think it contains?  One possible place where this might originate is the part where you do `CStr(shape.Index)`.

Comment: @Craig This is handled by the library GeoJson.Net (https://github.com/GeoJSON-Net/GeoJSON.Net/blob/master/src/GeoJSON.Net/Feature/Feature.cs). It passes back a valid Feature when I debug. The feature class does not contain any code with DISM in it. Moreover, I don't believe Newtonsoft would be able to serialize the Feature object as it would be an invalid Json. This leads me to believe that ```serializedData``` is a valid json and it gets corrupt when writing the file using the StreamWriter. When I step through and debug code, the contents of ```line``` have always contained valid data.